# Sympy 'solve' returns 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, sympy

I am using JuypterLab trying to solve a simple algebra problem:

```
3 * r**0.25 * s**0.75 = 14.086
```

I need to solve for s for values of r between 3 and 17.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas  
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, solve




s = Symbol('s')

expr = 3 * 18**0.25 * s**0.75 = 14.086

sol = solve(expr)

num = sol[10]
num
```

When I run the code I get the `list out of range error`

I also tried

```
s = Symbol('s')

expr = 3 * 18**0.25 * s**0.75

sol = solve(expr)
u = 14.086

num = sol[u]
num
```

When I run this code I get  `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

I would like to find the value of `s` for values of `r`
between `3 and 17`.

Comment: See nearly duplicate question and suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70549166/1089161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equations in sympy are written using `Eq()`. You can call `solve` with such an equation (or a list of multiple equations). You can tell `solve` that you look for an expression for `s` given `r`, by providing `s` as a second parameter.

The result of `solve` can take a few different forms, depending on the equations. Usually it is a list, and in this case there is only one expression that solves for `s`, so a list with one element.  (E.g. a quadratic equation could have multiple solutions.)

The result of `solve` often isn't a single number, but a symbolic expression. In this case, it is an expression involving the variable `r`. To get a value for `s` for a specific `r` (e.g. `r=10`), `expr.subs(r, 10)` can be used. Sometimes the solution is numeric, but still in its symbolic form (e.g. `sqrt(2)`).  Calling `.evalf()` will give a fully numeric solution.

```py
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq, plot

r = Symbol('r')
s = Symbol('s')

equation = Eq(3 * r**0.25 * s**0.75, 14)
sol = solve(equation, s) # [7.79846345438935/r**(1/3)]
s_of_r = sol[0]
for ri in range(3, 18):
    si = s_of_r.subs(r, ri).evalf()
    print(f"for r={ri} the corresponding value for s={si:.6f}")
```

Sympy can also do some basic plotting:

```
plot(s_of_r, (r, 3, 17))
```

[image: plot of s vs r]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first error "When I run the code I get the list out of range error":

- this is because sol is a one element list, and you are trying to access the tenth element that doesn't exist.

Regarding the second error "When I run this code I get list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

- this is because to access a position of a list you are trying with a decimal, which besides not working it doesn't make sense

As for the output of `sol` it is [0.0].

Isn't the code bellow what you are looking for? Cause It seems to me you wanto to find out the output of the expression when s is 14.086, right?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas  
import sympy as sym
from sympy import Symbol, solve

s = Symbol('s')

expr = 3 * 18**0.25 * s**0.75

y = expr.replace(s, 14.086)
print(y)
```

Instead, if you want to find the value of `sol` given a expression value you can use this approach

```
# equation example 3 + s, given an output of 5
y = solveset(Eq(3 + s, 5), s)
print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you recommend a better method to solve the problem for the value `s`?

Comment: I've edited the comment with a possible solution to what you are maybe looking for... so you are trying to find out the output of the expression when s is 14.086 right?

Comment: So you've only need to do `y = expr.replace(s, 14.086)` and `y` will contain the output

Comment: This is the equation: `3 * r**0.25 * s**0.75 = 14.086`.
I need to solve s for values of r between 3 and 17.

Comment: I've added the other approach, of finding out the value of `sol` given a expression value. If you encounter more issues, this is a great page to look at: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html#solving-equations-algebraically