# Find Indifference Curve Points

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following Cobb Douglas utility function:

```
x**0.35 * y**0.65
```

The initial basket of goods yields a utility of `25`.

I want to know how `y` changes for different values of `x`, e.g., `x \n [6,15]`

```
z = solveset(Eq(x**0.35 * y**0.75, 25), y)
```

Is there a way to compose this problem using an array for values of `x` and a loop?
I'm also wondering if there is not a better command than `solveset`.

Comment: You can also draw a plot: `plot_implicit(Eq(x**0.35 * y**0.75, 25), (x, 6, 15))`

Answer (score 1):

I think `nsolve` is a better choice here since you don't need a symbolic solution, just a numerical one. `nsolve` needs an initial guess so after finding 1 value, that value will be used as the initial guess for successive values:

```
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> eq = x**0.35*y**0.65 - 25
>>> xx = list(range(6,15+1))
>>> yy = [nsolve(eq.subs(x,xx[0]), 1)]
>>> for i, xi in enumerate(xx[1:]): yy.append(nsolve(eq.subs(x,xi), yy[i]))
...
>>> for i,j in zip(xx,yy):
...   print(i,j.n(2))
...
6 54.
7 50.
8 46.
9 43.
10 41.
11 39.
12 37.
13 36.
14 34.
15 33.
```

Comment: You can also use `solve(Eq(x**0.35 * y**0.75, 25), y)`.