# Solve single variable equation using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a single variable equation

```
y = 240 * x / (32 - x)
```

I want to solve the equation for all integer values of `x` between `0` and `10`

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548427/sympy-solve-returns-list-index-out-of-range-error), but am not able to figure out how to adopt it to my problem.

Here is an example of something I tried.

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq, plot

r = Symbol('r')


equation = Eq(240 * r / (32 - r)
sol = solve(equation) # [7.79846345438935/r**(1/3)]

              print sol
```

It does not work; and further it does not implement the `range` I would like.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: @yuuuu thank you for taking an interest in this problem. I have updated the question with an example of something I have tried.

Comment: The code as shown is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
for x in range(0, 11):
  y = 240 * x / (32 - x)
  print("for x =", x, " y =", y)
```